# The radio button <b-form-radio-group> is not checked (turning blue)

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, radio-button, radio-group, bootstrap-vue

I'm using `Bootstrap-vue.JS` to make a group of radio button. I have a reset function to have one of radio button checked. when I call the function, the value of the radio button is change as I expected, but the radio button itself does not showing its changed (the circle is not turning blue)

here is the **template**

```
<b-row md="9" align-h="center">
 <b-form-group>
  <b-form-radio-group
   id="radio-group-1"
   v-model="voc_type"
   name="radio-options"
  >
   <b-form-radio value="Request">Request</b-form-radio>
   <b-form-radio value="Complain">Complain</b-form-radio>
   <b-form-radio value="Saran">Saran</b-form-radio>
   <b-form-radio value="Pujian">Pujian</b-form-radio>
  </b-form-radio-group>
 </b-form-group>
</b-row>
{{ voc_type }}
```

Here is the **initialization** when the `vue` is created

```
export default{
 data{
  return{
   voc_type: 'Request',
  }
 }
}
```

Here is the **reset function**

```
reset(){
 this.voc_type= 'Request'
}
```

when I call the `reset()`, the output of `{{ voc_type }}` is "Request" as I expected, but the radio button is not turning blue. `idk` why..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I implemented a reset buttons, it works as expected now:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-row md="9" align-h="center">
      <b-form-group>
        <b-form-radio-group id="radio-group-1" v-model="voc_type" name="radio-options">
          <b-form-radio value="Request">Request</b-form-radio>
          <b-form-radio value="Complain">Complain</b-form-radio>
          <b-form-radio value="Saran">Saran</b-form-radio>
          <b-form-radio value="Pujian">Pujian</b-form-radio>
        </b-form-radio-group>
      </b-form-group>
    </b-row>
    {{ voc_type }}
    <b-btn @click="reset()">Reset</b-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      voc_type: 'Request'
    };
  },
  methods: {
    reset() {
      this.voc_type = 'Request';
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

There is a typo in your data function due to this the Vue reactivity probably didn't work correctly

```
  data() { <-- correct this line 
    return {
      voc_type: 'Request'
    };
  },
```

Comment: sorry i had a typo in that data function, my real code is good. but it's really weird to see my code works now, i haven't make any changes in my code yet.. hmmm :V

thanks for the answer tho..

Answer (score 0):

During my development of the nuxt app, I found a very clean way to use the b-form-radio buttons.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-group>
      <b-form-radio-group v-model="selectedOption" :options="options" name="name"></b-form-radio-group>
    </b-form-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options: [
        { value: 'option1', text: 'Option 1' },
        { value: 'option2', text: 'Option 2' },
        { value: 'option3', text: 'Option 3' }
      ],
      selectedOption: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```